# Is there a way to quickly select which file is displayed in Xcode's Assistant Editor?

Tags: xcode

My current way of selecting the file to be used in the Assistant Editor is quite cumbersome if I don't just want the automatic counterpart. I have to choose manual, then navigate all the way to the file.

Is there a way to use something like the Open Quickly dialog (command-shift-o) but have it apply to the Assistant Editor? Or even just a faster way than navigating through a list of files?

Comment: Drag a file from the navigator to the file path bar at the top

Comment: Press `Cmd+Shift+O` to show Open Quickly, type the filename you want, and then press `Option + Enter` to open it in the assistant editor. I think you can also `Option + Click` from the Project Navigator, or right click and `Open In Assistant Editor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the project navigator is open on the left, press "option" and click on the file that you want to open in the assistant editor. If the assistant editor isn't already showing, it will appear with that file. If the assistant editor is already showing, it will show the file.

Comment: Awesome! And as chedabob said this works with the Open Quickly dialog as well!

Answer (score 2):

Open the Xcode preferences and click Key Bindings. Then type "Assistant" into the search box to show a number of useful commands related to the assistant editor:

[image: preferences image]